# Set up hibernate 5: sessionFactory cannot be resolved to variable

Tags: java, hibernate

Im following this quick start:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/quickstart/html/

The problem: Im getting

```
sessionFactory cannot be resolved to variable
```

at this line:

```
sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory(); why?
```

Here is the rest of the class:

```
import javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry;
import javax.transaction.Transaction;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import ch.makery.model.Employee;  

public class HelloWorld {
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application!
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();
        try {

            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had trouble building the SessionFactory
            // so destroy it manually.
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
        }

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

       session.beginTransaction();
       //session.save( new Employee() );
       //session.save( new Employee() );
       session.getTransaction().commit();
       session.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put all the code of your class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a variable `SessionFactory sessionFactory` like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
 try{
 ...
  sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
...
```